# Play Framework 1.2.7 bootstrap jobs database writes failing

Tags: java, playframework-1.x

Using Play Framework 1.2.7, I have a class that extends `play.jobs.Job` that performs database writes (MongoDB using Play Moprhia plugin)

Here's an abbreviated example:

```
/* controller */
public static void doThings(@Required String id) {
  User me = User.findById(id);
  notFoundIfNull(me);

  new MyJob(me).now();
}

/* MyJob */
public class MyJob extends Job {
   private final User me;

   public MyJob(User me) {
     this.me = me;
   }

   @Override
   public void doJob() {
      int newValue = me.someInt;
      newValue++;
      me.someInt = newValue;
      me.save();
   }
}
```

**Here's the weird part** (weird to me anyway):

The write in the `doJob()` method does happen the first time the job is executed, sometimes a second time, but any additional instantiations of this job the write never occurs. No exceptions are thrown.

If i just remove the `extends Job` from `MyJob` and then just call the `MyJob` class by instantiating it myself and calling `doJob()` it works every time:

```
/* controller */
public static void doThings(@Required String id) {
   User me = User.findById(id);
   notFoundIfNull(me);

   new MyJob(me).doJob(); // assumes this class no longer Extends Job
}
```

I've been using Play now for 4+ years and have never seen this kind of behavior, and i'm at a loss as to what actually is happening.

Comment: Can you wrap your `doJob()` method body into a `try {...} catch (Throwable t) {logger.error(t, "...");}` block and see what happened? Also are you able to set a breakpoint inside `doJob()` and track down the execution?

Comment: i ran the code through the debugger, and here's the thing. when stepping through the code, it works. all the time. consistently works as it should. when i disconnect the debugger, then the phantom not-writing-to-the-DB thing appears again. no exceptions being thrown.

Comment: Are you using JPA? I suspect JPA's entity manager state is attached to a context, meaning your current action handling thread. While you are executing it in a separate thread, you will probably try handling that by yourself

Comment: Yes, using JPA (via Play Morphia's plugin implementation) and i think you may be correct in that i'm 90% confident that the condition i describe only occurs if you do a `new MyJob(me).now();` and if let Play schedule the execution (via `@Every`) it seems to be correct. I have some more verification to do.

Comment: Sorry I am a little bit confused. Play Morphia doesn't implement JPA (I know this clearly b/c I am the author of Play Morphia). If you are using P-M and got that issue then thing will get interesting and deserve a good analysis. If you can send me a simple package that reproduce the issue I might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think could be a (not handled) conflict on Morphia plugin and special on Context.
I'm sure there is something very similar in JPA model for Play1, where there is two contexts.

From your code I notice the object is loaded by Controller Context, and saved in Job Context.
When you do without job, Morphia still use the Controller one.

Try to pass only id and reload inside Job, or try to use JPDA remote debug, trap every call (inside controller and job), go deep inside Play framework and compare context object.

Good luck